# Foreach loop not looping through

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, custom-post-type

I have a foreach loop which is only returning the `title` of the latest post. For example, I have the post `test` as the latest post in `products` and in the loop defined below, when doing `var_dump`, it only dumps the title for the latest post called "test".

Why is this?

**Approach:**

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'        => 'products',
        'post_parent'       => 0,
        'posts_per_page'  => 15,
    );
    $products = get_posts( $args );

    if ($products){
      foreach ($products as $product) : setup_postdata( $product ); 
        var_dump(get_the_title());
      endforeach;
      wp_reset_postdata();

    }
?>
```

Comment: Try echo count($products); See if the post count is more than one.

Comment: Try removing post parent and check again. I think you only have one item

Comment: _“Why is this?”_ - because https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/setup_postdata/#more-information

Answer (score 0):

```
      foreach ($products as &$product) : setup_postdata( $product );
```

Please try this in your foreach loop.

Comment: Always do `unset($product);` after the loop for loop variables that are references. Because references behave strangely when used in a second loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
if ($products){
      foreach ($products as $product) : setup_postdata( $product ); 
        echo get_the_title($product->ID));
       // or echo $product->post_title;
      endforeach;
      wp_reset_postdata();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's strange but when you're wanting to use template tags along with `setup_postdata()` you need to use the global `$post` variable. `setup_postdata()` doesn't actually set that variable it sets some related global variables and runs the `the_post` action. You can see what happens [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/setup_postdata/)

To do what you want to do with out passing ids etc for every template function call you would need to setup your loop like this.

```php
global $post;
foreach ( $products as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    // Your code here.
}
wp_reset_postdata();// Reset the global $post variable and re-setup postdata.
```